How to solve Linq to SQL: Cast not valid error on designer page
Is anyone aware of the reason why publishing a WPF application with ClickOnce would result in a "Specified cast is not valid." error?
When attempting to open the design window for Linq to SQL shown below, the app behaves as expected and opens the designer before publishing.

However, once the application is published the design doesn't open and throws the error. I also can't drag and drop tables from the server explorer panel.
To get around this I deleted the PublishProfiles folder created by ClickOnce, within the Properties folder of the application, and the Linq to SQL designer behaves as intended. I have recreated the app multiple times before realising what caused the error and have replicated the issue every time.
Note: The error does not occur during runtime and the application works as intended. I just can't change the tables from the designer. I have to manually add the tables to the ".dbml.layout" and ".designer.cs" files.

Maybe this is better suited as a bug report to Microsoft? Use the feedback button in Visual Studio.
To easier get help, provide more details, like step-by-step instructions to enable someone to reproduce the error. What exact version of OS, Visual Studio, etc are you using?  Run Visual Studio with logging and share more details about the exception and call stack of the exception.

Wait, you have an app in which users can open the DBML designer?

@Fredrick Thanks. Will submit a bug report. I'm working on Windows 11(22621.3593) and Visual Studio Version 17.9.2 targeting .Net 8.0. To be honest, I have no idea what I did to produce this error. I created the linqtoSQL class at the start of the year and only moved to publishing about 2 months ago. Also didn't need to go into the Linq designer for a while so I noticed about 1 month ago that the designer didn't want to open.

@Gert, nothing that out of the box. Its just a WPF app that pulls data from an SQL database on your server. The error is thrown in visual studio when I attempt to access the designer to add or modify tables.

Tying the problem to the existence of publish profiles was an immediate help to me. I can temporarily delete the publish profile to work with the LINQ to SQL ORM Designer.
